# Google maps api fastest route around traffic

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I have a SPA that I need to be able to provide the user directions between two points. I want the directions to work that same way that they do currently on the web version of google maps. IE. https://www.google.ca/maps/dir/ in the hosted by google web version when you request directions it will give you the fastest route considering traffic... (See Screenshot)

[image: Google maps fastest route with traffic]

Currently when I issue the request using the following code it only returns a single route that does not consider traffic.

```
var directionsService = this.get('directionsService');
  var directionsDisplay = this.get('directionsDisplay');
  directionsService.route({
      origin: new google.maps.LatLng(this.get('currentLocation.lat'),this.get('currentLocation.lng')),
      destination: new google.maps.LatLng(toAddress.lat,toAddress.lng),
      travelMode: 'DRIVING',
      provideRouteAlternatives: true
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
```

Does anyone know thr correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check number of routes returned by [`DirectionService.route`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#DirectionsService), the callback will have a `DirectionsResult` object with an array of `DirectionsRoute`, which contains the information about the legs and steps its composed.

If its only returning 1 route, try to set `provideRouteAlternatives` to true in your `DirectionsRequest` object.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

TyBourque.
I think current google map API doesn't support direction map with traffic layer.
It is only available using embedded map API.

If you have already found the best solution (not using embedded map API), please write here

Regards

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking Ask Question. You can also add a bounty to draw more attention to this question once you have enough reputation.

Comment: Hi, awh112
I have already answered the solution is to use embedded map API.
I think this is the answer to above question.